# why I am getting " 'some class' does not contain a definition for 'some method' " error while the class has that method?

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli

I am trying to finish a simple tutorial for using c++ library with c# console application.
Here I have a simple class library:

**cpp file:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "ClassLibraryCPP.h"

using namespace ClassLibraryCPP;

void myClass::test() 
{
    Console::WriteLine("hello cpp/cli!");
}
```

**header file:**

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace ClassLibraryCPP
{

    public class myClass
    {
    public:
        void test();
    };
}
```

**and now here is my c# console:**

```
using ClassLibraryCPP;

namespace ConsoleApplicationCS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myClass testClass;
            testClass = new myClass();
            testClass.test();
        }
    }
}
```

and I get this:

> 'myClass' does not contain a definition for 'test' and no extension
>   method 'test' accepting a first argument of type 'myClass' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But I have made `myClass` and `test` method `public` so why `.test()` is not visible to console application?

---

Update:
adding ref to make managed class and then rebuilding the C++ project (by right clicking and rebuild not just rebuilding the solution) solved the problem.
I also found this question related:
[C# code can't "see" the methods in my C++ dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168128/c-sharp-code-cant-see-the-methods-in-my-c-dll)
I still don't get how this works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTRTY-fOIe8&t=1800s

Comment: In the cpp file, use `void ClassLibraryCPP::myClass::test()  {...}`

Comment: Do you do dllexport?

Comment: @IvanRubinson, no, I did not use dllexport.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your class managed:

```
public ref class myClass
{
public:
    void test();
};
```

Change method declaration:

```
void ClassLibraryCPP::myClass::test()
{
  Console::WriteLine("hello cpp/cli!");
}
```

Comment: From a C# you are referring to a C++ project or a library you get in the result of a build? Haven't you forgotten to rebuild the project? (sometimes it happens :) )

Comment: I get it as a syntax error like the test() is underlined red. I tried rebuild many times. :(

Comment: same happening to me as well.