# C# code can't "find" exported function in a DLL, Works in C++ test program

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke

I created a C++ (native) DLL that exports one function and I'm trying to call in from C# (managed) code and I receive runtime error that the function name can't be found in my DLL.

Here's the code of the DLL:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "Device.h"

// This is an example of an exported function.
DEVICE_API bool DeviceAvailable(void)
{
    return false;
}
```

The header exports the function like:

```cpp
#ifdef DEVICE_EXPORTS
#define DEVICE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DEVICE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DEVICE_API bool DeviceAvailable(void);
```

In C# I import the function as such:

```cs
.. enclosing code ...
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("Device.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool DeviceAvailable();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
}
```

When I call `NativeMethods.DeviceAvailable()`, I get an error on invocation:

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException
>   HResult=0x80131523
>   Message=Unable to find an entry point named 'DeviceAvailable' in DLL 'Device.dll'.

The `MessageBox` function works fine when called by the program (C#). A C++ test program is able to find and invoke the DLL function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find an entry point when calling C++ dll in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109590/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-when-calling-c-dll-in-c-sharp)

Comment: On top of that, the C's `bool` is not `UnmanagedType.Bool`. `UnmanagedType.Bool` is [`BOOL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#BOOL). You want [`MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53899333/11683).

Answer (score -1):

I guess your problem related to access settings on function level when creating the mentioned functions ic DLL.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168283/10743722)

you can find a useful links could help you to understand the case better and to find the best solution.